# \setmainfont cause "\scriptfont4 is undefined" error with nicematrix package

Tags: math-mode, fonts, nicematrix

This example compiled with xelatex or lualatex give rise to this error

> \scriptfont4 is undefined (character 49).
>  \c_math_toggle_token

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\frac11 & -\frac12 \\
\frac13 & \frac14 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2020, 2021 or 2022, with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, it works properly with both compilers in all versions. Maybe you have some custom versions of packages/fonts/compilers that are causing problems? Or maybe it is a Windows/MikTeX only problem?

Comment: @M I can with tl 2022

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I tried on Overleaf, so it has to be caused by a recent change (their TL 2022 is from July or something I believe).

Comment: Does `\variablefam=-1` help?

Comment: @mickep not this one, I think this is a macro layer change (somewhere)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I saw the other one, and since somebody linked to this one, I just assumed it was the same issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}
$1$

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
! \textfont4 is undefined (character 49).
l.8 $1$
     
?
```

Loading in the other order avoids the error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
$1$

\end{document}
```