# \textfont-1 is undefined, \scriptfont-1 is undefined with LuaTeX and unicode-math from MikTex

Tags: luatex, miktex, unicode-math

I just installed the MikTex updates (2022-11-25) and now even the simplest document will not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$a_b$
\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

```
! \textfont-1 is undefined (character 119887).
l.6 $a_b$
       
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

! \scriptfont-1 is undefined (character 119887).
l.6 $a_b$
       
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
```

Removing the subscript or the unicode-math package solves the problem in this minimal working example. These are the packages that were updated:

[image: Updated packages part 1]
[image: Updated packages part 2]
[image: Updated packages part 3]

MikTex diagnosis:

```
ReportDate: 2022-11-25 15:16:38
CurrentVersion: 22.11
SetupDate: 2018-03-20 09:53:00
SetupVersion: 2.9
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 183f49e / 2022-11-18 11:10:21
OS: Windows 6.3.9600
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2022-11-25 15:02:57
LastUpdate: 2022-11-25 14:25:35
LastUpdateDb: 2022-11-25 15:05:23
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9

The following issues were detected:
  1: minor issue: You are running MiKTeX on an unsupported version of Windows.
```

Comment: possibly related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666409/setmainfont-cause-scriptfont4-is-undefined-error-with-nicematrix-package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Miktex uses a luatex version which seems to have a bug. Adding `\variablefam=-1` seems to fix it for now, but I will report the issue in the miktex issue tracker too.

```
\variablefam=-1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$a_b$
\end{document}
```